# Getting base_url into a PHP file of symfony3 framework

Tags: php, laravel-5, symfony

I am beginner into the symfony framework and I want to get the base url of

symfony3 framework into the view file. I did R&D and get how to get the base url into twig file using this.

```
 {{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}
```

But my view

Not twig file it it is .php file

So I don't know how to use the base url in the view .php file.

I get the base url into the head.blade.PHP file of Laravel framework using:-

```
<?php echo URL::to('/'); ?>
```

I want to like this into symfony3 framework.

Comment: what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As explained on [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) : in symfony you have to create routes.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="site_home")
 */
public function homeAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

In twig, you can then call the routes like this :

```
{{ path('site_home') }}
```

You also can get the route in the controller and pass it to your view :

```
$homeUrl = $this->get('router')->generate('site_home');
```

Comment: OP is looking for non-twig solution, so this might not work.

Comment: No I am talking about the view file actually  I am using the metronic theme and I have to give the assets folder path into head.php view file so i want to the base url I am not talking about controller

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **base_url** in `controller` and then pass it to the `view` file.

To get the **base URL** in controller,

```
$base_url=$this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

And pass `$base_url` to view and access it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$link = $this->generateUrl('routeToPrint',array(),UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Where 'routeToPrint' is your annotation route. It returns a URL.
You also need:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
```

At the top of your file.